# Why is encapsulation in C# important?

Tags: c#, .net, encapsulation

At the moment I'm learning C# and the author of the book I'm learning with emphasizes encapsulation.

But I don't exactly understand why.

So what are the benefits of encapsulation?

Comment: Did you want to use google but ended up in SO by accident?

Comment: Look for basic OOP principles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the same reasons it is important in other languages.

- Encapsulation hides the implementation of a program, module, or type.
- It allows the type to perform logic when managing its state, thus disallowing possible invalid states for an instance.
- It allows the type to change the way it works in the future at the source level, without bothering the code outside of it. This is good because it allows the developer to focus at one problem at a time, without having to understand every part of the code base.
- It allows you to deploy updated versions of various modules, often without requiring the whole program to be rebuilt.

Comment: In the case of a "closed" holistic program - e.g. a mobile app - and when the logic is reasonably small, does it still make sense to encapsulate data members (I control/know all consuming members of the property)? I tend to still write accessors as a function of habit, but I often am looking out for cargo-cult code & think sometimes the accessors are pointless

Comment: @Coruscate5 I believe in applying your common sense above all. That being said, because I tend to program against interfaces instead of classes (even if I'm only working entirely with code I've written), I always go for properties. The fact that properties are so easy to type out in C# means that I get all the benefits of reserving my right to change the implementation later, without having to do anything complicated or writing boilerplate (typing out `{ get; }` or `{ get; set; }` requires hardly any effort). If something else happens to work best for you, I think you should do that instead.

Comment: I think this the answer I was looking for - it's difficult to parse the ideal from practical implementation when reading strong opinions from other software engineers. "Because it's easy" is a perfectly valid additional benefit that purists tend to shy away from..